# Running a excel macro crash when passing a com variant

Tags: c++, excel, vba, com

When running our application, it is crashing in the following line of code,
`*pResult = g_pExcel->Run(Temp1,argVariant);`

Below is the code. I am not able to find why it is crashing. Is there any type conversion problem?

```
CExec::CallRunVbtFunc(BSTR MacroName,
                        SAFEARRAY** ArgVals,
                        int *pResult)
  {

      _bstr_t Temp1 (MacroName);

      CComVariant argVariant(*ArgVals);
      argVariant.vt = VT_ARRAY | VT_BSTR;

      *pResult = g_pExcel->Run(Temp1,
                               argVariant);

      return S_OK;
  }

Public Function MyTesting() As Long
    Dim aa(1) As String
    aa(0) = "aaa"
    aa(1) = "bbb"        

    TheExec.CallRunVbtFunc "Macro3", aa

    End Function

Sub Macro3(argc As String, argv As String)

    TheExec.WriteComment "Called Macro2 with args*************** "

End Sub
```

Comment: Excel->Run takes argument like Run(MacroName, arg1, arg2, arg3, ......). But here we are passing argVariant (which has 2 values in it) as an argument. So I think that's the problem. How to split it and pass the value.

Comment: If you used #import in your C++ code then you can't really skip try/catch to diagnose `_com_error` exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

1. The Run Methode only takes VARIANT arguments and no arrays. See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.application.run)
2. Excel like all other VB scripting languages and OLE automation can handle only safe arrays of VARIANTs. Please check if your SAFEARRAY is realy of this type (`SafeArrayGetVartype`). Otherwise you need to transpose the array into a VT_ARRAY|VT_VARIANT safe array!

Comment: Yes. The parameter passed to run method is a variant (argVariant is of type CComVariant). Also it is transposed to array argVariant.vt = VT_ARRAY | VT_BSTR